# Looking for a "read it later" tool with rss reader

Tags: bookmark, rss, feed-reader

I'm looking for a pocket like tool that allows saving articles for later reading, but I want to be able to also add blogs or other rss feeds

Should work from web and Android

Comment: While I'm aware of several read-it-later apps, and also a bunch of RSS feed readers, I never came across an app that combines both in the way you want it to be, i.e. adding single pages and feeds alike. Good hunting, though – but be prepared to rather have to use two apps, one that takes care for your feeds and one to store articles for later reading.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with [Feedly](https://feedly.com)

This is available on various platforms - web, mobile apps, browser plugins, etc.

You can also export the articles that you wish to save to external applications such as Evernote.

Comment: While it has a "read it later" list, there doesn't appear to be a simple way to add links from the browser (the chrome extension doesn't support this feature)